# Duarouter Error

Tags: java, simulator

I'm working at an application in java, which simulates traffic (SUMO). I'm calling from my application douarouter to compute routes. As a result (after creating some routes) I get this:

```
Error: The vehicle type 'Default' occurs at least twice.
```

I have no idea where this is coming from. I suppose you can use a vehicle type for more than one vehicle.

Comment: It's hard (nay, impossible) to debug code without any code.

Comment: @Takendarkk What, did you lose your crystal ball? How irresponsible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you define the vehicle and especially the **vType** twice?

An example from [Sumo at a glance](http://sumo-sim.org/userdoc/Sumo_at_a_Glance.html):

```
<routes>    
   <vType id="type1" accel="0.8" decel="4.5" sigma="0.5" length="5" maxSpeed="70"/>
   <route id="route0" color="1,1,0" edges="beg middle end rend"/>
   <vehicle id="0" type="type1" route="route0" depart="0" color="1,0,0"/>
   <vehicle id="1" type="type1" route="route0" depart="0" color="0,1,0"/> 
</routes>
```

How do you define your vehicles?

Comment: <routes>
<vType id="Default" accel="2.6" decel="4.5" sigma="0.5" length="5" maxSpeed="70" /><vehicle id="home-school-home-13333-1" type="Default" depart="26432" color="0.29411766,0.49411765,0.79607844"><route color="0.29411766,0.49411765,0.79607844"></route></vehicle>

Comment: aha, you should probably close the xml tags for route and vehicle, not nest them:
<routes> <vType id="Default" accel="2.6" decel="4.5" sigma="0.5" length="5" maxSpeed="70" /><vehicle id="home-school-home-13333-1" type="Default" depart="26432" color="0.29411766,0.49411765,0.79607844"/><route color="0.29411766,0.49411765,0.79607844"/></routes> (yes, xml is crazy)

Comment: cool! maybe you can accept my answer then :)